# PHP/MySQL Query repetition

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is supposed to be used to book lectures at a university. When a user enters the details of the lecture they would like to attend the code executes all the queries (2) and posts to the DB.

Also the statement "`if ($totalrows<=5)`" is not working (no error), this should lock the number of bookings to 5 to a lecture above that and a message is echo'd. Still a newbie at this and will appreciate any help.

```
<?php
session_start();
$usernm   = "root";
$passwd   = "";
$host     = "localhost";
$database = "swift";

mysql_connect($host, $usernm, $passwd);
mysql_select_db($database);

$existingusername = $_SESSION['myssession'];

$Unit_id   = $_POST['Unit_id'];
$User_name = $_POST['User_name'];
$Date      = $_POST['Date'];
`
`
$Lecture_id = $_POST['Lecture_id'];
$Room_name  = $_POST['Room_name'];


if ($Unit_id == "0001") {
    $values    = "SELECT * FROM lecturedetails WHERE Unit_id='0001'";
    $result    = mysql_query($values);
    $totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($totalrows <= 5) {
        $savevalues = "INSERT INTO delegate_booking VALUES('$Unit_id','$User_name','$Date','$Lecture_id','$Room_name')";
        $saveresult = mysql_query($savevalues);

    } else {
        echo "Bookings are full or late booking";
    }


    if ($Unit_id == "0002") {
        $values    = "SELECT * FROM lecturedetails WHERE Unit_id='0002'";
        $result    = mysql_query($values);
        $totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($totalrows <= 5) {
            $savevalues = "INSERT INTO delegate_booking VALUES('$Unit_id','$User_name','$Date','$Lecture_id','$Room_name')";
            $saveresult = mysql_query($savevalues);

        } else {
            echo "Bookings are full or late booking";
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="LOGOUT.PHP">
    <input type="submit" value="LOG OUT"/>
</form>

<tr>
    <td><a href="Delegate.html">Back to Delegate member area</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: try to echo $totalrows and bring us the value

Comment: This code should go nowhere near `book lectures at a university` It is horrible (sorry but it is). Has severe sql injection holes. Uses outdated deprecated features and overall look like something a php newbie would construct... You should start by removing all mysql_* methods with non deprecated methods and read up on sql injection.

Comment: And your programming question is? (And if this is lecture, what did you read up so far, anything you understood or is it just that you guess and thought, why not dump to Stackoverflow, it's full of clever gals?)

Comment: If you want to validate whether or not there are five or less rows inside a table matching a condition, you need to check the same table for the count of rows as you insert rows into.

Right now you check one table (`lecturedetails`) but then you insert into a different one (`delegate_booking`).

Instead, check for the row-count in the same table (e.g. `delegate_booking`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've been given contains duplicate code, unnecessary variable checks (but also misses input validation (!)), the nesting is broken and the client library outdated since long.

The following is an example how to heal the most of those issue but not the missing input value checks as there is no specs about the string formats you use there.

```
<?php
session_start();
$existingusername = $_SESSION['myssession'];

$Unit_id   = $_POST['Unit_id'];
$User_name = $_POST['User_name'];
$Date      = $_POST['Date'];

$Lecture_id = $_POST['Lecture_id'];
$Room_name  = $_POST['Room_name'];

$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=swift;charset=utf8', "root", "",
    [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
);

$count = function ($Unit_id) use ($pdo) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lecturedetails WHERE Unit_id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$Unit_id]);
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
};

$insert = function ($Unit_id, $User_name, $Date, $Lecture_id, $Room_name) use ($pdo) {
    $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO delegate_booking VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $result = $insert->execute([$Unit_id, $User_name, $Date, $Lecture_id, $Room_name]);
};

if ($count($Unit_id) <= 5) {
    $insert($Unit_id, $User_name, $Date, $Lecture_id, $Room_name);
} else {
    echo "Bookings are full or late booking";
}

?>

<form action="LOGOUT.PHP">
    <input type="submit" value="LOG OUT"/>
</form>

<tr>
    <td><a href="Delegate.html">Back to Delegate member area</a></td>
</tr>
```

This hopefully helps you a bit. The logical problem that you check the wrong table for the row-count as I've commented earlier is still not fixed, too.

Comment: Small tweaks helped to sort out the issue. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong parenthesis. `if($Unit_id=="0002")` is inside `if($Unit_id=="0001")` which should not be correct.

> $existingusername=$_SESSION['myssession'];
>
> $Unit_id=$_POST['Unit_id']; $User_name=$_POST['User_name'];
>   $Date=$_POST['Date']; $Lecture_id=$_POST['Lecture_id'];
>   $Room_name=$_POST['Room_name'];
>
> ```
> if($Unit_id=="0001")
>   {                <-- start here
> ```
>
> $values="SELECT * FROM lecturedetails WHERE Unit_id='0001'"; $result=mysql_query($values); $totalrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
>
> ```
>     if ($totalrows<=5)
>     {
>     $savevalues= "INSERT INTO delegate_booking VALUES('$Unit_id','$User_name','$Date','$Lecture_id','$Room_name')"; 
>     $saveresult=mysql_query($savevalues);
>
>     }
>     else
>     {
>     echo "Bookings are full or late booking";
>     }
>
>
> if($Unit_id=="0002")
>   { $values="SELECT * FROM lecturedetails WHERE Unit_id='0002'"; $result=mysql_query($values); $totalrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
>
>     if ($totalrows<=5)
>     {
>     $savevalues= "INSERT INTO delegate_booking VALUES('$Unit_id','$User_name','$Date','$Lecture_id','$Room_name')"; 
>     $saveresult=mysql_query($savevalues);
>
>     }
>     else
>     {
>     echo "Bookings are full or late booking";
>     }
>   }
>   }                 <-- end here, why?
> ```
>
> ?>